# Checking if all data has been returned from server in Knockout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am displaying data from the user on the user page and i would like to notify the user once all the data has been loaded and there is no more data to retrieve from the server using knockout.

**Knockout script**

```
     $.views.Roster.GetPage = function ( pageNumber) {
        $.grain.Ajax.Get({
            Url: Views.Roster.Properties.Url,
            DataToSubmit: { pageNumber: pageNumber, id: Views.Roster.Properties.Id },
            DataType: "json",
            OnSuccess: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                $.views.Roster.RosterViewModel.AddUsers(data);
            },
            OnError: function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
                var _response = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
                $.pnotify({ title:_response.title, text: _response.Message, type: _response.TypeString});
            }
        });
    };
    $.views.Roster.ViewModel = {
        RosterUsers: ko.observableArray([]),
        TotalRoster: null,
        CurrentPage: ko.observable(1)
    };

$.views.Roster.BindModel = function (data) {
        var self = $.views.Roster.ViewModel;

        $.views.Roster.ViewModel.TotalRoster = ko.computed(function () {
            return self.RosterUsers().length;
        });

        $.views.Roster.RosterViewModel.AddUsers(data);
        ko.applyBindings($.views.Roster.ViewModel);
    }
    Next = function () {
        var _page = $.views.Roster.ViewModel.CurrentPage() + 1;
        $.views.Roster.ViewModel.CurrentPage(_page);
        $.views.Roster.GetPage(_page);
    };

    $.views.Roster.RosterViewModel = function (data) {
        $.views.Roster.RosterViewModel.AddUsers(data);
    };

    $.views.Roster.RosterViewModel.AddUsers = function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            $.views.Roster.RosterViewModel.PushUser(value);
        });
    };

    $.views.Roster.RosterViewModel.PushUser = function (user) {
        $.views.Roster.ViewModel.RosterUsers.push(new $.views.Roster.UserViewModel(user));
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say 'once all the data has been loaded', I assume you mean when the GetPage method finishes loading a single page of users, as that is the only data loading that I see in the code above.  Here is one way you can do it:

First, create an observable somewhere that you can bind to to tell the user if data is loading

```
$.views.Roster.ViewModel = {
    RosterUsers: ko.observableArray([]),
    TotalRoster: null,
    CurrentPage: ko.observable(1),
    DataIsLoading: ko.observable(false)
};
```

And add some markup that shows something in the UI when data is loading

```
<div data-bind="visible:DataIsLoading">Data is Loading, please wait...</div>
```

Then set DataIsLoading before you make the ajax call, then reset it when the call is done

```
$.views.Roster.GetPage = function ( pageNumber) {
    $.views.Roster.ViewModel.DataIsLoading(true);  // Add this!
    $.grain.Ajax.Get({
        Url: Views.Roster.Properties.Url,
        DataToSubmit: { pageNumber: pageNumber, id: Views.Roster.Properties.Id },
        DataType: "json",
        OnSuccess: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
            $.views.Roster.RosterViewModel.AddUsers(data);
            $.views.Roster.ViewModel.DataIsLoading(false);  // Add this!
        },
        OnError: function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
            var _response = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
            $.pnotify({ title:_response.title, text: _response.Message, type: _response.TypeString});
            $.views.Roster.ViewModel.DataIsLoading(false);  // Add this!
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this i will go ahead and work with this and see what i get. If it helps i am loading 20 on page and when the user scrolls to the button of the page the Next() method loads another 20 on the same page. This is where i want to know when there is no more data is available to load so i can tell the user - all done.

Comment: I see that you have a div showing that the data is loading. How can i switch that to have it say "Data is loaded" at the bottom of the page?

Comment: `<div data-bind="visible:!DataIsLoading()">Data is Loaded</div>`